# Create text over image html

Tags: html

I am currently trying to write HTML code specifically for android.

What I want to do is creating HTML that will;

1. Take picture either using built in camera or from phone photo gallery
2. the user will be able to write text over the image
3. Save the photo in phone gallery.

Comment: You can't do that with only HTML. You have to use javascript and stuff

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible in pure html. You will need to add some amount of Javascript. This can either be done in a separate file linked to your html or inside  tags.

Regarding the specifics of what JS you need I have no idea. Start with steps, first setup the layout using HTML and then add functionality step by step. In this case something like:

1. Start with two buttons (one to open image, one to take image)
2. Add functionality
3. Open image with placeholder text
4. Make the text over image editable using input forms

It's best to work step by step and ask specific questions to help you complete each step.

These links may help:
[Access camera from a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024770/access-camera-from-a-browser)
[Text over image in javascript and css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47400301/text-over-image-in-javascript-and-css)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree that I have to include Javascript.

Comment: I have been searching online and this (https://syntaxxx.com/accessing-user-device-photos-with-the-html5-camera-api/) come very close to what I have in mind except for the text overlay. However I can't make it works..  is there probably changes code as the guide was written in 2014?